# Loading Issue while refreshing the page in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I create the header nav bar. the data of the navbar is getting dynamically.

```
const [navItem, setNavItem] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://localhost//wp-json/wp/v2/pages")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        data.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);
        setNavItem(data);
      });
  }, []);
```

But the problem is when I refresh the page it take sometime to load the data. But I don't want this how can I solve this issue?
[image]

[image]

Comment: You are making an API call to fetch the navigation menu items. Since its taking time for your app to receive the response from the API call, the menu won't be displayed till then. Can't you use static menu items in FrontEnd itself?

Comment: One way is to use a skeleton. For example: [ant design skeleton](https://ant.design/components/skeleton/) or  [mui skeleton](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-skeleton/)

Comment: I noticed you're fetching this data from localhost, is this file present in your own project directory? If yes, then you don't need to fetch, you can import it normally in your code. Otherwise, you can create a place holder of sorts. Display something on the navbar while the actual pages load, or implement a loader. (Because it will take time to fetch every time since in useEffect)

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackabuse.com/storing-data-in-the-browser-with-localstorage/
You can store the data in local storage the first time, and then check if the data is present. If it is, you can simply get it from here instead of calling API.

Comment: You should probably look at static- or server rendering of your react app. Have a look at frameworks like Next.js or Remix.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the useQuery hook. It will consistently fetch the source for the data. Normally, you should not have any lags or delay: [useQuery](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/overview)

Comment: This will still have to reload the data on a page refresh. If it's really about having the data directly after a refresh and avoid triggering an extra api call, and you want to use `useQuery`, have a look at the storage persisters. See https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/plugins/createSyncStoragePersister